# wifi and bluetooth not working in ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, reboot

**Hello Sir...!**
*Same problem is created twice when I install ubuntu twice in my laptop after some time when I install ubuntu same problem exists but after some time It was working properly without anything do.. but that time a problem was created my laptop battery was used after shutdown so that's why I reinstall ubuntu but same problem exists given blow I can't understand what's the problem I do update and upgrade all packages I do change setting in additional drivers but when I click on wireless network no any network is show...*

please help and tell me what is the problem and give solution enter code here.

[Check this for see all function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304524/wifi-not-working-also-bluetooth-in-linux-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment540301_304524)

Comment: so, the wireless network works after installing, but after some time, it stops working?

Comment: yes its working in my laptop but after install twice "ubuntu" same problem exists again

Answer (score 1):

After fresh install of your ubuntu run
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Option 1.Then open additional drivers tab in driver manager and it shows ur unused drivers.. select them and apply changes....(it won't show this options unless u run above command)
Option

2.if this doesn't work then connect  bootable pendrive of Ubuntu u installed on your pc and do additional driver selection thing again....reboot and this will solve your problem
(It worked on my Ubuntu and mint too)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here in comments has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45760/discussion-on-answer-by-sardapv-wifi-and-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu).

Comment: I install ubuntu 14.04 but not working same probem is created "wifi is disabled by hardware switch" this problem is created but in bios I saw no any problem is created I set restore default but still its not working same problem as like as ubuntu 16.04

Comment: See if there is any button to turn on wifi.. follow above comments in additional driver manager tab.. If still it doesn't solve then..its time to consult your brand.. service centre or company